# Hibernate saveOrUpdate does not update existing record instead it saves the record as new entry

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

Been searching for SO since this morning but I can't find the right answer to this question, I'm doing an update to a record using the ID as reference, but instead of updating the app inserts new entry of the existing record, the console is showing "insert into" instead of "update". here are snippets from the app:

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/saveCustomer")
public String saveCustomer(@ModelAttribute("customer") Customer customer) {

    customerService.saveCustomer(customer);

    return "redirect:/erp/list";
}

@GetMapping("/showFormForUpdate")
public String showFormForUpdate(@RequestParam("customerId") int id, Model model) {

    Customer customer = customerService.getCustomer(id);

    model.addAttribute("customer", customer);

    return "customer-form";
}
```

DAO implementation:

```
@Override
public void saveCustomer(Customer customer) {
    Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    currentSession.saveOrUpdate(customer);
}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="customer")
public class Customer {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
private int id;

@Column(name="company_name")
private String companyName;

@Column(name="company_email")
private String companyEmail;

@Column(name="company_address")
private String companyAddress;

@Column(name="contact_no")
private String contactNo;

@Column(name="company_tin")
private String companyTin;

public Customer() {

}

public String getContactNo() {
    return contactNo;
}

public void setContactNo(String contactNo) {
    this.contactNo = contactNo;
}

public String getCompanyName() {
    return companyName;
}

public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
    this.companyName = companyName;
}

public String getCompanyEmail() {
    return companyEmail;
}

public void setCompanyEmail(String companyEmail) {
    this.companyEmail = companyEmail;
}

public String getCompanyAddress() {
    return companyAddress;
}

public void setCompanyAddress(String companyAddress) {
    this.companyAddress = companyAddress;
}

public String getCompanyTin() {
    return companyTin;
}

public void setCompanyTin(String companyTin) {
    this.companyTin = companyTin;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
```

Comment: The only way I can see this happening is if the entity really does not already exist, in which case you would get an `INSERT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing setter method in your bean:

```
public int setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

and that's why when you are adding model attribute, it is not setting id value in your bean.